# How to fix an html column width to the max width of its content?

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I am trying to format a table for an input form as follows.  The table looks a bit like this:

```
       Name:
Time of day:
```

and so forth, where each of those field labels is then followed by the input field proper. 
My goals is to have a table with two columns, one for the field labels, the other for the input fields, such that:

- The size of the left column is automatically determined by the longest field label, so that field labels are never wrapped around.
- The input fields themselves extend as much to the right as possible.

I know of course that I can fix the left column to be e.g. 20em long, and the other column 100%, but this is not what I am asking -- I don't want to have to measure and then enter a fixed width like 20em; I would like the width to be automatically derived from the width of the longest item in that column.  This sounds like a fairly common wish; is there a way to do it simply?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If any of the answers to your question are helpful, feel encouraged to give them an upvote by clicking the up arrow. When your question has been answered, please mark the appropriate answer as 'Correct' by clicking the checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `white-space: nowrap;` CSS style, as in the code below. Of course, you will want to add margin or padding between the two columns so the colon (`:`) isn't pressed against the input box. [**jsFiddle example of the code below**](http://jsfiddle.net/EGMJf/)

*HTML:*

```
<table class="fullWidth">
    <tr>
        <td class="nowrap">Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nowrap">Time of Day:</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*CSS:*

```
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;  
    width: 1px;
}

.fullWidth {
    width: 100%;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;   
}
```